# dir="rtl" IE7 input fields change position on focus

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, right-to-left, dir

I need to convert an existing layout to right-to-left for different languages i.e., arabic, hebrew, etc. and I'm having issues with IE7 - imagine that. I used this awesome tool to convert the css, https://github.com/ded/R2, which worked very well. However, when the layout is rendered in IE7, giving any input element focus causes the element to reposition itself on the other side of the screen i.e., about 540px to left.

The ltr version of the layout has the form element inside a 200px container div that is positioned to the left of the main content area, a basic to column layout. The rtl version is a mirror image i.e., the 200px form container is positioned to the right of the main content area.

The two column and main containers are templates that get loaded into parent containers on the base html page i.e., there are divs for the sidebar and the main content area templates. I noticed that moving these parent containers around changes where the repositioned input elements are placed when clicked. These parent elements default to the width of their parent, which is 870px, and it looks like the input elements are repositioning themselves to the left inner border of these elements. I tried changing the width of these parent containers and that did nothing, any ideas?

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this problem by setting the parent container dir attribute to ltr and then input elements to rtl.